# How to assign access rights to users and managers in security in odoo 10?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-10, access-rights

I am creating a module named loan management. In this module, I need to achieve some security rights. They are User – Can create/view/edit only his/her Loan and Manager – Can create/view/edit his/her team Loans.

My code in security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
<record model="ir.module.category" id="employee_loan_approval_access">
        <field name="name">Loan Approval</field>
        <field name="sequence">1</field>
    </record>

<record id="employee_loan_approval_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="employee_loan_approval_access"/>
</record>

<record id="employee_loan_approval_employee" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Loan Department</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="employee_loan_approval_access"/>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

In csv file:

access_employees_employees_Loan_Department!employeeloanform_employeeloanform!   model_employeeloanform_employeeloanform!employee_loan_approval_manager  !1! 1   !1! 0
access_employees_employees_employee_Department! loanpayment_loanpayment!    model_loanpayment_loanpayment   !employee_loan_approval_employee    !1! 1!  1!  0

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you need to add inherit between group1 and group2

```
 <odoo>
    <data>
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="employee_loan_approval_access">
            <field name="name">Loan Approval</field>
            <field name="sequence">1</field>
        </record>

    <record id="employee_loan_approval_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="employee_loan_approval_access"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    </record>

    <record id="employee_loan_approval_employee" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Loan Department</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="employee_loan_approval_access"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('employee_loan_approval_manager'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
    </odoo>
```

Comment: Do I want to change anything in the settings?

Comment: @Naveen No  don't change anything.